# Natural logarithm using while loop in Python

Tags: python, math, while-loop, user-input, break

The function: y(x) = ln 1/(1-x)

How do I write a Python program to evaluate the above function for any user-specified value of x, where ln is the natural logarithm (logarithm to the base e)? I am to compulsorily use a `while` loop so that the program repeats the calculation for each legal value of x entered into the program. When an illegal value of "x" is entered, I used `break` to terminate the program.

I have tried using the following code but it seems not to run appropriately:

```
import math

n = int(input("Enter the number to be converted: "))

while n >= 0:
    if n <= 0:    
        break

print("Your number is not positive terminating program.") 
    
x = math.log(n) * 1/(1-n)

print("The Log Value is:", x)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not appropriately"?

Comment: It doesn't run and it had no error messages. I use a python 3.7 though

Comment: So you mean that you start the program and then nothing happens and then the program finishes?

Comment: Exactly! Can you kindly help me with the correct code?

Comment: Do you not even see the prompt "Enter the number to be converted:" ?

Comment: Yes I do, but nothing seems to happen after that.

Comment: The function you have described in the text is different from what you have written in the code. Do you want to calculate `log(1 / (1 - x))` or `log(x) * 1 / (1 - x)`?

Comment: I want to calculate this log(1 / (1 - x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import math

while True: # infinite loop, to be halted by break
    x = float(input('Enter the number to be converted: ')) # get the input
    if x >= 1: # is the input legal?
        print('The function cannot be evaluated at x >= 1.')
        break # break out of the loop if the input is "illegal"
    y = math.log(1 / (1 - x))
    print('The log value is:', y)
```

1. First, your program might fall into an infinite loop; if you enter `n = 1` for example, then `n >= 0` is true and `n <= 0` is false, so your program runs the `while` loop indefinitely.
2. A "legal input" to the function must be a (real) number (strictly) less than 1. If `n == 1`, then you are doing division by zero. If `n > 1`, then you are entering a negative number into the log function.

In the suggested code, I am checking only the "numerical legality" of the input; i.e., entering an empty string would throw an error. But I think that is beyond what you are asked for in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

So really you just don't have the proper lines in the while loop

```
import math
valid = True

while valid == True:
    n = int(input("Enter the number to be converted: "))
    if n <= 0:
        print("Your number is not positive terminating program.")     
        valid = False
    else:
        x = math.log(n) * 1/(1-n)

        print("The Log Value is:", x)
```

Comment: `True` and `False` are spelled like that in Python. `while valid == True` should just be `while valid`.

Comment: How do i kinda like terminate the loop using a break statement When the n = -1 and so on?